# PHP to telnet router and execute traceroute command to a destination print live output

Tags: php, html, telnet, traceroute

I need to create a GUI using php to telnet router and execute traceroute command to a destination ip and print live output on the html page.

The current output:

[image]

The current code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Telnet-Router</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

while (@ ob_end_flush());
$cmd='traceroute 8.8.8.8';

$telnet_con = fsockopen("172.16.1.2", 23, $errno, $errstr, 10);

if(!$telnet_con)
{
  echo "Connection failed\n";
  exit();
}
else
{
  fwrite ($telnet_con, "myusername\r\n");
  sleep(1);
  fwrite ($telnet_con, "password\r\n");
  sleep(1);
  fwrite ($telnet_con, "$cmd\r\n");
  fwrite ($telnet_con, "exit\r\n");
  echo "Connected\n";
  echo '<pre>';

  while (!feof($telnet_con))
  {
    echo fread($telnet_con, 4096);
    @ flush();
  }
  echo '</pre>';
  fclose ($telnet_con);
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you forgot to tell us what your problem is...We know what you want to do, and we can see some code. But you make no connection between those two things. What's going wrong for you?

Comment: Actually this does not give me the traceroute output. It gives attached output. Thank You !!

Comment: Tried any of the solutions available on google? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+read+telnet+output&oq=php+read+telnet+output&aqs=chrome..69i57.7448j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Yes tried. But not worked. Because this need to be print the live output of the router.

Comment: Could you just please edit the question to make it clearer? This would help others a lot to help you out with this issue. Then just remove the unnecessary posted comments. Good luck!